# Import NLTK : no module NLTK corpus

Tags: macos, nltk

I have installed NLTK. Here's an image of the installation log.

[image]

When i use `import nltk` i get an error:

> "No module named NLTK.corpus"

Here is a screenshot.

[image]

What could be the cause?

Comment: attaching images and screenshots - is a bad approach. Use code snippets and or cite formatting tools, and attach it as a text.

Comment: Do you have both Python 2.7 and 3.4? I've been struggling too for it because pip was somehow installing nltk for one but not for the other.

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Python 3 or 2? and Please use code snippets as @Farside said. It is hard to change tabs each time to see your problem.

Comment: What I find curious is that the error contains `NLTK.corpus`, not `nltk.corpus`.  It suggests there is a problem somewhere with the case folding on the filesystem or Python import level.  Perhaps a broken ipython environment?  The image contains "The directory `/Users/mlal/Library/Caches/pip/http` ", so it looks like osx.

Answer (score 14):

I think I had the same problem. So, downloading all the packages at once (since question didn't specify).

Start python and then import the packages, exit python and upgrade nltk. Modify the 'all' to download a specific corpus. Took me awhile to complete the 'all' download, I separately downloaded framenet_v15 and restarted the 'all' after. Upgrade nltk when the download is complete.

```
$ python
>>>import nltk
>>>nltk.download('all')
```

exit python

```
$ pip install --upgrade nltk
```

Answer (score 5):

To fix this, you should rename your file to something else, say nltkXXX.py. Also make sure to remove "nltk.pyc" from your directory if it exists, since this will also be loaded (it's the byte compiled version of your code). After that, it should work fine.

Comment: This answer assumes the question writer has created a python file called `nltk` which is being seen by the Python interpreter first.  I think that is not correct, because `import nltk` is automatically attempting to import `NLTK.corpus`, which means the real `nltk` is starting to load.

Comment: This may not be the answer, but it fixed _my_ issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the latest version of python, then try installing nltk using pip and the wheel downloaded from here: 
    http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Then in command prompt, use the command:
    pip3 install

This should install nltk correctly.
After that check the installation in python using the command:
    import nltk

and download the nltk data required using:
    nltk.download()

Comment: THANK YOU for posting this.  But any idea why python setup.py install didnt do that for us?

Answer (score 3):

If you find (Import NLTK : no module NLTK corpus) that type of error .

Make sure your saved file not be the name like (nltk.py).
so just rename your file name (like rename nltk.py to example.py ) or something else:

I hope it will help you.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you has using PyCharm IDE, you should have install NLTK from the IDE's own tools [File -> Settings -> Projetct Interpreter -> Install (button '+') -> Install Package].